# How to find a package / function?

Tags: python, function, package

I am trying to run a python `script.py` that has the line:

```
from reptile.signals import new_signals
```

`reptile` is a python package (not sure if that's the correct terminology) that someone wrote.

Later in the scripy.py, there is the line:

```
var = new_signals.Timing(clock=True)
```

`Timing` is obviously a function in the `new_signals` code if I understand correctly.

I need to find this `Timing` function to change some things, but I'm having problems trying to locate it.

Could someone explain to me how I track down the path please?

Comment: Have you already installed the `reptile` module?  Then you can examine its code and docs.  If not, you'll have to search the net for something similar.  A starting point is the source of this `script.py`.  With a name like that, I suspect `reptile` is a module written specifically for some tutorial or blog.  I don't find anything like it on `pypi`.

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) most web links produced by `python reptile` has nothing to do with the programming language.  That makes me think this is a made up module, not something widely published.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - yes the reptile module is just written by a colleague. It is installed. I do want to examine its codes and docs, but I'm not sure where to find it on the remote machine where everything is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing the entire `reptile` module and check its `__file__` attribute. You should be able to follow the files to where `Timing` is located.

```
import reptile
print(reptile.__file__)
```

Comment: Interactive sessions also allow `help(reptile)`.